# Get Portion of Class Name, in order, on Web Page Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way using Javascript,  to pull a portion of a class name in order (top to bottom) on a web app? I have an issue where I need to get information on a 3rd party web app we are integrating into our site. **I can't change their code**.  What I want to do is take the class name (e.g. class="index solid-shape-large-rating-fair AnalysisCategory" or class="index solid-shape-large-rating-poor AnalysisCategory" etc.) and grab the value after "rating-" in the class name (class="index solid-shape-large-rating-[**want this value**] AnalysisCategory"). So in the example I have, I would get back, in this order, top to bottom, "fair", "poor" and "excellent". Is this possible? If so how? Please be aware there will be more mark-up between elements in my example, if that impacts the answer? I just cleaned up the non-related code for presentation purposes. They aren't stacked directly on top of each other as in my example.

```
///////Top Element//////////
<div class="stack-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center index-area">
                    <label tabindex="0">YOUR INDUSTRY BORROWING HISTORY</label>
                    <div class="index solid-shape-large-rating-fair AnalysisCategory">
                        MODERATE RISK
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

//////////////Middle Element////////////////////

<div class="stack-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center index-area">
                    <label tabindex="0">TENURE OF YOUR BUSINESS</label>
                    <div class="index solid-shape-large-rating-poor AnalysisCategory">
                        POTENTIAL CONCERN
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
////////////Bottom Element/////////////

<div class="stack-item" style="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center index-area">
                    <label tabindex="0">YOUR BUSINESS PROFITABILITY</label>
                    <div class="index solid-shape-large-rating-excellent AnalysisCategory">
                        EXCELLENT
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The answer depends upon the structure of the HTML. If the div in question is always a child of a "row" under a "stack-item" then you can just grab all such divs under this heirarchy. Then grab the class of these child divs and attempt to parse the classes applied to it, such as with regex.

Comment: This works$(function() {
 $('[class*="solid-shape-large-rating-"]').each(function(i, e) {
  var result = this.className.match(/solid-shape-large-rating-(.*?)\s+/);
  console.log(result[1]);
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on another site.

```
$(function() {
$('[class*="solid-shape-large-rating-"]').each(function(i, e) {
    var result = this.className.match(/solid-shape-large-rating-(.*?)\s+/);
    console.log(result[1]);
    });
});
```